# Vue: Property accessed during render but not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, render

I receive an error when I load my website. [image]

My code looks like that:

```
              <div v-if="bookings">
                <div class="row">
                  <div
                    class="col-12 m-2"
                    v-for="booking in bookings"
                    :key="booking.booking_id"
                  >
                    <BookingListItem :booking="booking" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
......

data() {
    return {
      boookings: undefined,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      user: (state) => state.patient,
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    getBookings() {
      this.id = this.user.id;
      console.log(this.id);
      return axios
        .get('URL/patients/${this.id}/bookings')
        .then((response) => {
          this.bookings = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten: " + error.response);
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getBookings();
  },
};
```

I defined the rendered data and even added an v-if to my template. Where do I make a mistake?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think all you have to do is `bookings: []`. Define it as empty array in `data()`

Comment: It might be typo because in data function name of array is **boookings** `data() {return {  boookings: undefined  }; }` and in v-for loop spelling is different **bookings**

Comment: @Jatinder Yes you are right. In `data()` there is 3 `o` `boookings`. lol.

Comment: @Jatinder what a fail..

Comment: @Erenn yes, works now like that. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I renamed boookings to booking and defined it like the code below, it worked perfectly.

```
  data() {
    return {
      bookings: [],
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Cause you define it as undefined in your data object.

Make the axios call inside async created() function and assign it to this.bookings, then it should be gone.

use await instead of callbacks on the getBookings and then do this.

```
async created(){
this.bookings = await this.getBookings();
}
```