# Properties defined in data() can't be accessed from create() hook

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I'm currently trying to use VueJS 3 and Axios to access a simple API and display its result data.
Unfortunately, it seems that anything beyond the sample ping example eludes me.

The issue i've been running into is thus: it seems the data() method gets called after *both* created() and mounted(), and that therefore the values it's supposed to instantiate (in my sample code, random_vids and count aren't available while getRandomVideos() and testMethod() execute.).

This makes changing them in the methods called by create() impossible, as the reference does not exist yet.

I'm using the Options API and the created() hook. See the below code, commented with the logs and warnings I get when I execute it:

```
<template>
  <p class="title">some title idk</p>
  <div>
    {{random_vids}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "home_fitness",
  methods: {
    data() {
      return {
        random_vids: [],
        count: 1
      }
    },

    async getRandomVideos(){
      const path= "http://localhost:5001/random_videos"

      try {
        const res = await axios.get(path);
        this.random_vids = res.data; // Warn: Property "random_vids" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
      } catch (error) {
        this.errorMessage = error;
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
    // this test method included in the hopes it makes my error easier to reproduce (also, i needed to make sure this wasn't async or axios shenanigans)
    testMethod() {
      console.log(this.count); // log: undefined
      this.count = 2;
      console.log(this.count); // log: 2
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.getRandomVideos();
    this.testMethod();
  }
};
</script>
```

It seems the variables do get instantiated *eventually*. When I update the source file and save it, vue hot updates my changes into the running app; testMethod() is not ran again (no logs) so I assume getRandomVideos isn't either, but line 4 in my example suddenly gets filled with the expected data from the API.

Previous tinkering with logs confirms that getRandomVideos() successfully fetches the API data from localhost:5001/random_vids, and API server logs confirm the request isn't reran. The code I've written successfully fetches and stores the data, and since a file update causes it to be written in the DOM, I suppose it must have *some* idea of where it's supposed to go, but I truly don't understand why it doesn't do so right away.

I've perused the guide and multiple answers and even found [simlar questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70215753/vue-property-accessed-during-render-but-not-defined), but nothing that solved my problem. I suppose I'm making a very simple mistake, but I can't find which one. I've probably missed something fundamental about Vue, but I cannot figure out *what*.

So, why is data() seemingly executed *after* create()? Why is the data available but doesn't appear until Vue hot updates the file after a source change? Why isn't *count* available despite being defined in data()? How do I get random_vids to correctly display on line 4 of my example on page load?

Comment: `data` is component option, not a method. "So, why is data() seemingly executed after create()? " - it's not executed at all, you could debug this

Comment: @EstusFlask It *was* a very simple mistake after all, and I do not know how I missed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is not meant to be a method.  It is one of the "options" of Options API, where `methods` is another, **separate** option.

Change this:

```js
methods: {
  data() {
    return {
      random_vids: [],
      count: 1
    }
  },
  async getRandomVideos(){
...
}
```

To this:

```js
data() {
  return {
    random_vids: [],
    count: 1
  }
},
methods: {
  async getRandomVideos(){
...
}
```